# Notebook cell properties: Count cell number. Count edited cells

Tags: notebooks, cells

I have a *Mathematica* notebook with more than 20 cells, including some closed.

- How can I programmatically count the exact number of cells?
- How can I know how many of them have not been edited?

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: I tried to make your question easier to read. Please check that my editing did not change the meaning of your question. [Edit] your question if you have more information to add or any clarifications to make.

Comment: All input cells in a notebook are edited at some time or another, so you need to tell us what criteria you will apply to classify a cell as edited on not edited. Perhaps, some algorithm applied to the cell history data?